# How do you convert a varchar in the format of HH:MM:SS to a int value in minutes. Using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, type-conversion, integer, varchar

I am trying to convert an varchar formatted in HH:MM:SS to an int value that represents the total amount of minutes.
The table has a varchar called: 'duration' and a total amount of students called: 'amount_of_students'.

I want to divide the duration of the class in minutes by the amount of students.

I have already found the following code, but this does not work in MySQL and seems to only work in MS SQL:

```
select duration,
       (convert(int, left(duration, locate(':', duration) - 1)) * 60 +
        convert(int, left(right(duration, 5), 2))
       )
from Class
```

I am currently getting the following error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'int, left(duration, locate(':', duration) - 1)) *
> 60 +
> convert(int, le'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can use the functions `hour` and `minute` on such HH:MM:SS formatted strings: they will be interpreted as time values:

```
select hour(duration) * 60 + minute(duration)
from Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time_to_sec()` and multiply by 60.  For a decimal value:

```
select time_to_sec(duration) / 60
```

For an integer:

```
select floor(time_to_sec(duration) / 60)
```